# How to change mc (midnight command) bash prompt on OS X?

Tags: bash, terminal

I observed that my custom bash prompt does not work on `mc`. How do I customize it?

Comment: WHere do you set your custom bash prompt?

Comment: My custom bash prompt is setup in `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that .bash_login files are only read when bash is run as the login shell. mc probably just calls a new shell which will read its startup from ~/.bashrc See [bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files) for details.

To make the shell run in a common way it is often suggested that you call .bashrc from .bash_login e.g.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: I did this and now I see the prompt correctly, still there is a difference: all ANSI escapes had vanished from mc prompts, it's not colored.

Comment: I suspect $TERM has been changed as man mc says it is " run it in a pseudo terminal,"

Comment: That bugreport https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/2027#comment:21 has clear answer:

>> Is there a way to get the prompt colors show up also in MC? 
> Unfortunately no. It is not supported, аll control sequences in the
> prompt are ignored.

Answer (score -2):

Read the INVOCATION section of the man page, it's there for a reason.  MC is most likely not launching a login shell and you are only configuring your prompt for login shells.

Comment: Excerpt from `man mc`: "An extra added feature of using the subshell is that  the  prompt  displayed  by  the Midnight Commander is the same prompt that you are currently using in your shell." - As you probably observed this is not true, the prompt is clearly not the same, in fact I suspect it's the default prompt for bash `bash-3.2$`.